# Karma can't find jasmine.js

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I run karma with grunt, karma use jasmine framework. When i launch my grunt task i got the following errors :

```
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "Mypath\node_modules\karma-jasmine\lib/jasmine.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "Mypath\node_modules\karma-jasmine\lib/boot.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "Mypath\node_modules\karma-jasmine\lib/adapter.js" does not match any file.
```

I can't understand why. When i copy/paste the path i found files.

This is my karma's file conf :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        preprocessors: {
            '**/*.directive.html': 'ng-html2js'
        },
        files: [
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/angular.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/angular-mocks.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/angular-ui-router.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/angular-ui/ui-utils.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/angular-animate.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/angular-messages.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/angular-file-upload.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '../../../Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: '**/*.directive.html', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: 'appNV.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
             { pattern: 'Test/Unit_Test/**/*.spec.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true }
        ],
        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            prependPrefix: '/',
            moduleName: 'directive.template'
        },
        basePath: process.cwd(),
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        reporters: ['progress', 'html'],
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        autoWatch: false,
        singleRun: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        htmlReporter: {
            outputFile: 'Test/units.html'
        }
    });
};
```

Anybody have an idea ?